# Strong params for nested model attributes in a form in a Rails 4 application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters, cocoon-gem

Im using Cocoon gem(https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) in my Rails 4 application connected to a Postgres database for building a nested model form. I have permitted the attributes of the nested model (owner) in my projects controller as follows

```
params.
        require(:project).
        permit(:name, :description,
               owners_attributes: [:name, :email, :miscellanous, :_destroy])
```

miscellanous column in owners table is of type json . Im unable to specify miscellanous correctly in the required params above. Suppose miscellanous can have the following keys: favorite_color and favorite_movie. How can i specify that in the strong params above ?

If i do the following:

```
params.
    require(:project).
    permit(:name, :description,
           owners_attributes: [:id, :_destroy, :name, :email, miscellanous_attributes: [:favorite_color, :favorite_movie] ])
```

I get `syntax error, unexpected ']', expecting =>`

How can i correctly permit the json column called miscellanous for the nested model owners using strong params ?

Comment: On which line do you get the error, because the strong parameters declaration seems perfectly ok at first sight. How do you define the json attributes, maybe something is wrong there?

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

1. You can permit a hash with unknown keys with an empty hash bracket.
2. Don't forget you need the ID for your owners.
3. Note the missing 'e' in miscellaneous.

Try something like this:

```
params.
    require(:project).
    permit(:name, :description,
           owners_attributes: [:id, :name, :email, miscellaneous: {}, :_destroy])
```